# Meaning of MsysObjects values -32758, -32757 and 3 (Microsoft Access)

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm quering the table MsysObjects for making a list of the objects in my database:

```
SELECT MsysObjects.Name, MsysObjects.Type
FROM MsysObjects
WHERE (((Left$([Name],1))<>'~') AND ((Left$([Name],4))<>'Msys'))
ORDER BY MsysObjects.Name;
```

I know the meaning of this values:

```
-32768 = Form
-32766 = Macro
-32764 = Report
-32761 = Module
1 = Table
5 = Query
6 = Linked Table
```

But what about -32758, -32757 and 3? Where do they stand for? Cannot find it on the web.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
Type   TypeDesc
-32768  Form
-32766  Macro
-32764  Reports
-32761  Module
-32758  Users
-32757  Database Document
-32756  Data Access Pages
1   Table - Local Access Tables
2   Access Object - Database
3   Access Object - Containers
4   Table - Linked ODBC Tables
5   Queries
6   Table - Linked Access Tables
8   SubDataSheets
```

-- http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=103811

Comment: Thanks! But should there be no "offical" information from Microsoft somewhere?

Comment: As far as I recall, MS does not want you poking around in system tables, it can do really horrible things to your DB if you do not know what you are doing. They are undocumented and people used always to post a warning when mentioning them. However, that seems to have stopped.

Comment: Well, for one, MS has promised (according to Michael Kaplan) that once something in a system table is used for something, it will always be supported. How you know the difference between used and unused objects, I haven't a clue, but there it is.

Answer (score 5):

I'd tend to avoid mucking about with the system tables. For one, temporary objects can show up there and confuse things. To get the same information, you can use:

```
  CurrentDB.TableDefs
  CurrentDB.QueryDefs
  CurrentProject.AllForms
  CurrentProject.AllReports
  CurrentProject.AllMacros
```

That's the documented way to get the information. Depending on undocumented system tables is not recommended.

Comment: AFAIK, a Macro will only be accessible from AllMacros if it is opened first, and there's no _reliable_ (*cough*SendKeys*cough*) way to open a Macro from code.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**
Create table "AccessObjectType"
Columns:

- TypeID autonumber
- TypeStr text
- ShowUser Yes/No
- ShowAdmin Yes/No

Populate the "AccessObjectType" table:

```
TypeID  TypeStr ShowUser    ShowAdmin

-32775  Module  False   True
-32772  Report  True    True
-32768  Form    True    True
-32766  Macro   True    True
-32764  Report  True    True
-32761  Module  False   True
-32758  User    False   False
-32757  Database Document   False   False
1   Table (local)   True    True
2   Access Object - Database    False   True
3   Access Object - Container   False   True
4   Table, linked ODB SQL   True    True
5   Query   True    True
6   Table, Linked Access Excel  True    True
7   Type 7  True    True
8   SubDataSheet    True    True
```

If you like, you can create another column called "SimpleType" for grouping of 1, 4 and 6 as simple type Table.

**Step 2**
Create Query "AccessObjectQ"
SQL:

```
SELECT MSysObjects.Id, 
       MSysObjects.Name, 
       [Name] & " (" & [TypeStr] & ")" AS NameAndType, 
       [TypeStr] & ": " & [Name] AS TypeAndName, 
       Abs([Type]) AS ObjTypeID, 
       AccessObjectType.TypeStr, 
       AccessObjectType.ShowUser, 
       AccessObjectType.ShowAdmin
FROM MSysObjects LEFT JOIN AccessObjectType 
  ON MSysObjects.Type = AccessObjectType.TypeID
WHERE (((MSysObjects.Name) Not Like "msys*" 
  And (MSysObjects.Name) Not Like "*subform" 
  And (MSysObjects.Name) Not Like "*_*" 
  And (MSysObjects.Name) And (MSysObjects.Name) Not Like "*SF" 
  And (MSysObjects.Name) Not Like "*SQ" 
  And (MSysObjects.Name) Not Like "*~*") 
  AND (((AccessObjectType.ShowUser)=True) OR ((AccessObjectType.ShowAdmin)=True)))
ORDER BY MSysObjects.Name;
```

**Step 3**
Create a table "AccessObjectVisibility"
Columns:

- ObjectID as long (create as a lookup using AccessObjectQ)
- UserVisible as Yes/No
- AdminVisible as Yes/No

You can now easily open this table (or a query) and select objects that you want users and admins to see in automatically populated lists you provide on forms.

**Step 4**
Create Query "UserAccessObject"

```
Select * from AccessObjectVisibility where UserVisible = True
```

Create Query "UserAccessForm"

```
Select * from AccessObjectVisibility where UserVisible = True and TypeID = -32768
```

Create queries: "UserAccessReport", "UserAccessQuery", "UserAccessMacro", etc.

**Step 5**" 
Create a custom reports menu using query "UserAccessReport" to populate a list box or combo box

Comment: Please indent your code parts with four spaces (or just select them and select the "code" button in the editor), this is not really readable.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - IIF is a drag, and the switch solution doesn't seem valid for SQL (I may have done something wrong).  I entered the values that Fionnuala offered into a new table named AccessObjectXref:

```
ID  ObjectType  ObjectDesc
1   -32768  Form
2   -32766  Macro
3   -32764  Report
4   -32761  Module
5   -32758  Users
6   -32757  DB Document
7   1   Table
8   2   DB
9   3   Container
10  5   Query
11  8   Subdatasheet
```

Then used the following SQL to create a list of object names and their counts.  Obviously you could include every record if you wanted:

```
SELECT objectdesc, Count(*) AS Expr1
FROM msysobjects,  AccessObjectTypeXref where type = objecttype
group by objectdesc order by objectdesc
```

Comment: jchad you should format your posts using [this syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Re David Fenton's proper answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994956/meaning-of-msysobjects-values-32758-32757-and-3-microsoft-access#4001999), here is Microsoft documentation of those techniques. There appear to be two distinct object models for Access:

- [Data access object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/microsoft-data-access-objects-reference):

  - [Database object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/database-object-reference-dao) has properties TableDefs and QueryDefs, which are collections of all the tables and queries in the database.
- [Access object model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/access/object-model):

  - [CurrentData object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.currentdata) has properties AllTables and AllQueries, which are collections of all the tables and queries in the database, with different sets of properties than TableDefs and QueryDefs have.
  - [CurrentProject object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.currentproject) has properties AllForms, AllReports, AllMacros, and AllModules, which are collections of those objects.