# Listing the permissions of a specific user or group in an MS Access security file?

Tags: sql, permissions, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to set some permissions for groups in our MS Access database using an *.mdw security file.

I'm on the "User and Group Permissions screen", and this is completely not ideal for finding out what permissions have already been set for a user concerning a specific object.

I'm given a list of `Users/Group Names` and I have no trouble finding my group there.

However...when I reach the `Object Name:` list, it is ridiculously long and I am unable to find which permissions have been assigned to the group due to the enormous number of objects that are found there.

The existing group has a very limited set of permissions (it appears that all of the Objects `Permissions` checkboxes are unchecked), there are at least a thousand of these for each of the `Object Types`: Table, Queries, Forms, etc...and I would like to find out which ones have Read Data, or Open/Run checked off for their permissions.

I've tried scrolling though the `Object Name:`s for my group but there are just too many to check without some sort of a query or code; there MUST be another way to do this.

I don't have access to the main account for the database, so I don't believe that I am able to write any code to find the answer.

I was able to obtain a list of objects using [a query specified here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994956/meaning-of-msysobjects-values-32758-32757-and-3-microsoft-access) but I am unable to find any relation between the objects and the Group Permissions.

Comment: You might consided using the ms-access tag rather than ms-access-2003 to give your question a wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly this user interface is clunky and I understand your trouble!

To set the permissions for a group, switch the Groups option under the User/Group Name list.

The permissions assigned to an object are shown by the combination of check boxes which can make it hard to see the current permission set up.

Select the group you want to modify and then use the Object Name list to select the object(s). This list is multi-select so if you want to give permissions to only a few objects, the best way is to select the whole list and clear the permissions and then set the permissions for the selected objects.

So, for instance, to assign read-only permissions to a group apart from two tables where they have read/write permissions, set the Object Type to 'Table'. Now select the entire list of tables including the '' item in the Object Name list and clear all of the check boxes apart from Read Data and Read Design (you can't clear the Read Design if you have Read Data selected). Click the Apply button. Now select just the two tables that you want to give read/write permission to in the Object Name list. Check the Update and Insert boxes and click Apply.