# What are the definitions of the 'Flags' field values in the MSysobjects Table

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

s***Note - don't play around in the MSysobjects Table ***
I'm Guessing they indicate whether the object is hidden or not?
(note that I'm have the values of MSysObjects.Type, I'm looking for **MSysObjects.Flags**).

---

So far I'm guessing:

```
Flag        FlagDescription

-2147483648 SystemStuff

-2147287040 SystemStuff

-2146828288 SystemStuff

0 Visible Object

3 Query for a form

8   Query

10  Table - System?

16  Query - Crosstab Visible

24  Query - Crosstab Hidden

40  Delete Query

136 Union Query
```

Note that I'm using the field to generate a combo boxes with a list of Queries and Reports that are Visible so end users can select and use them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meaning of MsysObjects values -32758, -32757 and 3 (Microsoft Access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994956/meaning-of-msysobjects-values-32758-32757-and-3-microsoft-access)

Comment: I've edited to clarify that I'm looking for MSysObjects.Flags not MSysobjects.Type.

Comment: Agree that this is no longer a duplicate of that question

Answer (score 4):

Here are some additional items with both Flags & Type field values.
For each type, 8 is added to the Flags value where the object is hidden.
System tables have various Flags values
In addition, some system tables are deep hidden (not visible from the navigation pane even if hidden objects / system objects are ticked). It is also possible to create deep hidden tables

Unable to layout clearly as a list, so please see the attached image instead

[image: MSysObjects type & flags values]

Comment: Format the list as code, then it will be formatted nicely (and readable).

Comment: Andre: Thanks for the advice - I did try that as well as list/block quotes etc!
Rink: Thanks for modifying this so the image is always visible as intended!

Comment: With table support now here, it would nice to have this as text. I have it as a markdown table, but I didn't want to create another answer just to do that. If OP or someone else can help, that would be excellent.

Answer (score 2):

You have most of the known ones,

```
Flag    Description
-2147352256 Contains Attachment Data ?
-32768  Form
-32766  Macro
-32764  Reports
-32761  Module
-32758  Users
-32757  Database Document
-32756  Data Access Pages
0   Select
1   Tables - Local Tables
2   Access Object - Database
3   Embedded Select Queries
4   Table - Linked ODBC Tables
5   Queries
6   Table - Linked Access Tables
8   SubDataSheets
16  Crosstab
32  Delete
48  Update
64  Append
80  Make Table
112 Pass-Through
128 Union
144 DDL
262144  ?
```

a couple of discussions on this. 
https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=224699

[Meaning of MsysObjects values -32758, -32757 and 3 (Microsoft Access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994956/meaning-of-msysobjects-values-32758-32757-and-3-microsoft-access)